# WS-Discovery with Apache CXF. How to specify device type?

Tags: web-services, cxf, onvif, ws-discovery

I'm going to use Apache CXF for ONVIF-compatible ip camera service. It uses WS-Discovery to find devices and services and [cxf supports it](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-discovery.html) out-of-box:

> The cxf-services-ws-discovery-service jar will register a
>   ServerLifecyleListener that will automatically publish the "Hello"
>   messages. It will also respond to any Probe requests that match the
>   services it has published.

How will cxf detect device type to send in `ProbeMatches` response? How can i specify that my device is ip camera (i need to set concrete device type in ProbeMatches response, `NetworkVideoTransmitter` for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into CXF source code (`WSDiscoveryServiceImpl` class) i've found the answer:

```
public ProbeMatchesType handleProbe(ProbeType pt) {
        List<HelloType> consider = new LinkedList<HelloType>(registered);
        //step one, consider the "types"
        //ALL types in the probe must be in the registered type
        if (pt.getTypes() != null && !pt.getTypes().isEmpty()) {
            ListIterator<HelloType> cit = consider.listIterator();
            while (cit.hasNext()) {
                HelloType ht = cit.next();
                boolean matches = true;
                for (QName qn : pt.getTypes()) {
                    if (!ht.getTypes().contains(qn)) {
                        matches = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!matches) {
                    cit.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        //next, consider the scopes
        matchScopes(pt, consider);

        if (consider.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        ProbeMatchesType pmt = new ProbeMatchesType();
        for (HelloType ht : consider) {
            ProbeMatchType m = new ProbeMatchType();
            m.setEndpointReference(ht.getEndpointReference());
            m.setScopes(ht.getScopes());
            m.setMetadataVersion(ht.getMetadataVersion());
            m.getTypes().addAll(ht.getTypes());
            m.getXAddrs().addAll(ht.getXAddrs());
            pmt.getProbeMatch().add(m);
        }
        return pmt;
    }
```

In brief - it iterates published services and compares QNames. If searched qname is found in published it's added into `ProbeMatch`. So i should implement and publish service with needed QName to fix it.

Comment: but where to put this code? should i override this method somewhere ?