# What wsdl to implement to add NetworkVideoTransmitter to supported ProbeMatch with CXF?

Tags: cxf, onvif, ws-discovery

Apache CXF implements `WSDiscoveryServiceImpl` to support `WS-Discovery`. And it iterates over published services to check supported Probes and requested: [WS-Discovery with Apache CXF. How to specify device type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267270/ws-discovery-with-apache-cxf-how-to-specify-device-type).

What wsdl should i implement and publish the service to add `NetworkVideoTransmitter` to supported Probes?

Answer (score 0):

After looking to the sources and debugging i've found one need just add properties to service impl:

```
@EndpointProperties(
        {
                @EndpointProperty(key = "ws-discovery-types", value="{http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl}NetworkVideoTransmitter")
        })
```